# An integration formula using Gauss-Laguerre method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Using Gauss-Laguerre method show that:

$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x+a}dx=\frac{a+3}{a^2+4a+2}+\frac{4}{\theta^5} $

where:

$ 0<\theta<1, a>0 $

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried.

Comment: I would like to show that :$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x+a}dx=\frac{a+3}{a^2+4a+2}+\frac{4}{\theta^5}$ , using Gauss -laguerre method under conditions cited in the question

Comment: I can read. I know that. What have you tried?

Comment: ok, i checked this link :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Laguerre-GaussQuadrature.html but i'm not up to  result